# Android gradle: Multi project build, top level build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-project Android build system. The structure of the project is as follows:

```
Root Dir
   |
    settings.gradle
   |
    build.gradle
   | 
    Apps
      |
       app 1
         |
         build.gradle
      |
       app 2
         |
         build.gradle
    |
    Libs
      |
       lib 1
         |
         build.gradle
      |
       lib 2
         |
         build.gradle
```

All the apps and libraries have common android configration.

At the Root level build.gradle I have the following:

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'android'
   android {
      compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
      buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

      defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 14
         targetSdkVersion 19
      }
   }
}
```

Next I thought of adding the following to the build.gradle in app 1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   sourceSets {
      main {
         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
         java.srcDirs = ['src']
         res.srcDirs = ['res']
      }
   }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot add extension with name 'android', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

In the gradle plugin for android, is there a way to have a "master android configuration" which can be extended by a sub-module?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with having `apply plugin` set in two different places, with two different plugin IDs?

Comment: Might be a dumb question, can one have an " android { ... } " section without applying the android plugin in the gradle file?

Comment: No, but you already applied `android` to all subprojects.

Comment: Sorry for more dumb questions, I am trying to understand how android plugin and gradle works in general. I need to apply two different plugins, one for library projects `android library` and `android application` for apps. In addition to this I need to have a `common android configuration`, which is applicable to all the sub-projects.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - and it has to do with how you are including your plugins.

In your "root" build file you have:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

In your app you have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Change the root to match the app plugin.